# REST API - Best practice to access embedded resources

Tags: mongodb, api, rest, embedded-resource

We use **MongoDB** and we provide **restful api** to access resources (not only collections).
For example I have a **devices collection**. Every device document has an **embedded array: carriers**. These are association classes for carriers, **without any unique id**.

```
{
   _id: ObjectId("..."),
   carriers: [
     {
         carrier: ObjectId("..."),
         bindingInterval: {
           from: ISODate("..."),
           to: ISODate("...")
         }
     },
     ...
   ]
}
```

In our service the uniqueness of carrier-binding determined by a compound of specific fields: carrier + from + to values.

*Question:*
What is the best restful practice to require these embedded documents? In many cases I **GET / POST / PUT / DELETE them individually**.

Otherwise it's just an example. We have embedded documents in many other cases.

*Ideas:*

1. I describe separately the compound parameters in the query below the main resource's id.
2. I define a virtual id for embedded documents using a mixin of these parameters and I generalize this approach for similar cases.

Comment: To be honest if you need to query particular resource via REST API, the best idea is to assign an unique ID to it. If you just need a collection filtering e.g. by *from* range, some resource query language will be useful.

Comment: The latter case is ready and complete with a satisfying query language as you wrote.
In the former case I think it's not necessary to add unique ID, because the specified fields ensure the uniqueness.

Comment: Fully agreed, however, the ID introduced will make querying easier.

Comment: Consequently I thought that i create a virtual ID that mix somehow the parameters, e.g. simple join or md5 and I don't store it, just use it for query.
I am looking for this case in restful tutorials but I didn't find anything about this, however it has to.
Or am I wrong and I mistake at the design of endpoint structure?
For the safety I would like that the API let modify these documents individually. Is it a bad design and I must modify these all at once? I don't know...

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understood you need to access the elements that are not assigned with any ID in a RESTful way.

First of all I'd add a separate endpoint for the carriers only. It will be:

```
/devices/{deviceID}/carriers/
```

I don't know why not assign an unique ID on mongo DB level (this seems to be the easiest option) but if it's not possible it's better to refer a given resource via an artificial compound key passed in path rather than sending the parameters separately via query string. So each time you return the collection of carriers assign each element a:

```
carrierID = md5(carrier+from+to)
```

With such a key you can easily refer every embedded resource via:

```
/devices/{deviceID}/carriers/{carrierID}/
```

It seems that it will be much easier to refer such resources via different endpoints.

The downside is that you need to recalculate the `carrierID` for all resources on the backend side to check if any of them matches the received one.

I see that you've an `ObjectId` for each carrier field. Isn't it unique? Why don't you use it?

Comment: /devices/{deviceID}/carriers/

That's the right way in the endpoint hierarchy.
But md5 needs aggregation in mongo-side, that has to calc every md5 value, as you said.
**carrierId** is not unique in the association class, because it's possible that one device could be in different intervals in the same carrier.
But I wrong, **from** value is satisfactory for the query.

Comment: So if `from` fulfills the uniqueness requirement I would use it as `carrierID`. If you do not want to pass it explicitly use md5 od other hash od it - it will affect performance as I already wrote.

Comment: Otherwise the problem is given, if we have more than one parameter for uniqueness.
But! I am not looking for the solution. I can resolve it. I need the most beautiful and generally accepted solution, if there is.

Comment: I'd go the way I suggested.

Comment: I would like to leave this question open yet.

Comment: Sure :) What objections do you have against my suggestions? Another way is to use a kind od resources query language.

Comment: I would like to avoid md5 aggregation on server side...
What do you mean: "kind of resources query language"?
Otherwise I have an other idea for polymorph association classes, because we have :) Then I define new query parameter(s) with name "uniqFields" and "uniqValues". Hmm... I can't belive that I'm walking on unexplored way :O Must be a trend

Comment: I guess this question more philosophical than scientific :)

Comment: If you want to avoid md5 on server side and have unique field (`from` as you stated) just use it. By resource query language I meant [RQL](https://github.com/persvr/rql), it's designed for advanced queries and resource filtering. It might be an useful idea as well.